# Best Vaadin component for a list of String

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

My issue is I have a simple List of Strings say

```
List<String> names = List.of("Frank","Joe","Eva");
```

All I want is display it on the UI. With some simple code like

```
ListComponent lc = new ListComponent.setItems(names);
```

I have tried it with **Table** which seems to work but code behind it is a bit boilerplate for this simple task(7-8 line of code).

I have tried also the **Grid** component and it works well when I want to bind a POJO to it , but with String.class type its a nightmare.

```
  Grid<String>  listGrid= new Grid<>(String.class) ;
  listGrid.setItems(names);
```

it doesnt work because I have to provide getters for the column, which String.class doesnt have for the value. So I did this:

```
 Grid<String>  listGrid= new Grid<>(String.class) ;
  listGrid.setItems(names);
  listGrid.addColumn(String::toString).setCaption("name");
```

It works! However unspecified columns also appear in the grid, so now I have 3 columns Byte,Empty,name. And I dont know why. Where are these comes from?

Comment: Remove all the unwanted columns first with `removeAllColumns().`

Answer (score 2):

What are the requirements for displaying them? Just to get them on the screen? Is Label enough?

```
for(String name: names) {
  mylayout.addComponent(new Label(name))
}
```

If you need selection, then maybe ListSelect or ComboBox are the go-to’s.

Comment: I want to display them and edit them. each line needs to be one element of the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the additional columns, one way is to do as was pointed out in a comment, i.e. do  `removeAllColumns()` before you go on creating your own columns.

Another approach would be to do `new Grid<>()` instead of `new Grid<>(String.class)`. The main difference is that the second constructor uses reflection on the provided class and automatically configures columns for anything that looks like regular Java bean properties.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly prefer to use `grid.removeColumnByKey` rather than `removeAllColumns()`
You can also use `grid.setColumns` to specify order of columns.

I will add link to vaadin documentantion for grid with java examples which is realy helpfull. [enter link description here](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples/configuring-columns)

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to adding the Strings in TextAreas. Because I needed some formatting, I added the text using StringBuilder.

```
List<String> details = getDetails(); 

 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

 for (String detail : details) {
     TextArea ta = new TextArea();
     ta.setSizeFull();
     ta.setMaxHeight("100px");
     ta.setValue(builder.append(detail).toString());
     ((Span) content).add(ta);
     ((Span) content).add(new Hr());
 }
```

The result is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

```
final Grid<String> grid = new Grid<>();
grid.setItems(new ArrayList<String>());
grid.addColumn(item -> item).setHeader("Value");
```